# Can jq parse json without containing double quote?

Tags: jq

```
curl http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json
{"message": "success", "timestamp": 1665708640, "iss_position": {"longitude": "-114.2621", "latitude": "8.5148"}}
```

I want to parse the json to get property `message`.

```
x=$(curl http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json | jq .message)
echo $x
"success"
```

I want to get `success` without containing double quote.

```
x=$(curl http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json | jq .message | sed 's/"//g')
echo $x
success
```

Can jq achieve same target with its some argument without piping to sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use jq's command-line option `-r`.